# Create Email through Google Apps API

Tags: gmail, google-api, google-apps

I want to dynamically create email addresses (and dispose them after a while), from my code. I've searched all over the web, but didn't find any API endpoint that allows people to create new email accounts.

I am using Google Apps for Businesses, so their documentation is made pretty well and indexed by Google, but still nothing. Did anyone do this, or has the link to a doc page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating and deleting user accounts can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/

Comment: Wohoo, it even has Zend Framework code. Thank you. Guess I'm not the expert googler I thought I was.

Comment: Hi , did you get any information about it . Me too stuck in it