# Is there an email service provider that allows the programmatic creation of addresses?

Tags: email, service

So I'm currently working on a project that requires the mass creation of email addresses programmatically, but I can't find any email service that allows this. Is there a way to create any number of email account without UI interactions?

Comment: Do they have to be separate email addresses? If you can use one account then try using tags. For example: `email+[UUID]@yourdomain.com` -- anything after the `+` will still go to the same address.

Comment: @DylanMoore i need them to look like they are diffrent people to the receivers. They need to have diffrent names , domains can be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If Google is an option for you, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112772/5949901) may be of help. Google accounts can be created through an API request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

More details here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users